# Can you use water you drank from for negel vasar

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, water, morning-day

What do the sources say about this case: someone drank from a water bottle - could they use the water remaining in the bottle for "negel wasser"?

And does it make a difference if when you drank the water you were tahor?

Comment: Your question is unclear. "if when you drank the water you were tahor". What do you mean "tahor". Do you mean that you have washed negel wasser? I have edited the first part of your question as I understand it.

Comment: In Hilchos Netilas Yedayim it is clear that water that remains after some of it was used is still considered unused.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69020/27180

Comment: It is not a problem ,even if an animal drank from it bdeved it is fine . Shulchan Aruch 160 ,מים ששתו מהם התרנגולים או שלקק (פי' שתיית הכלב נקרא לקיקה) מהם הכלב יש מי שפוסל ואין דבריו נראין אלא בין באלו בין בכל שאר בהמה חיה ועוף יש להכשיר: