# Netilas Yadayim with Water I touched

Tags: mistakes, netilat-yadayim-washing

I thought one may not wash Netilat Yadayim (for bread) with water that was touched (e.g. I accidently stuck my finger in the cup before washing). In fact, it may be used according to halacha. This leads me to ask, is this a common misconception, or purely my own mistake.

If this is a common belief, where does this arise from?

Is there any opinion which holds that such water is indeed invalid for Netila?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69005/touching-the-water-in-the-washing-cup-before-netilat-yadayim

Comment: The reason we wash each hand multiple times is to purify the water from the first wash, right? Wouldn't it follow that touching the water makes it impure?

Answer (score 2):

The Rema in OC 160:11 says it's not an issue, and most opinions seem to follow that. But the [Kaf Hachaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.160.11?lang=bi&p2=Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.160.61.1&lang2=bi) brings from the Imrei Esh that there is room for stringency:

> וכתב בשם חמיו הגאון מהר"ד דייטש שהיה מקפיד מאד שלא יגע שום אדם בידו במים שהוכן לפניו לנט"י וכמה פעמים שפך המים אם חשש שנגע בהם יד