# Water as a chatzitzah

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, mikvah-ritual-bath, stringency-chumrah, chatzitzah

I learned that Birkei Yosef holds that non-mikvah water may be considered a chatzitzah. That is why we make sure our hands are completely dry before we wash them ritually. It may be why some are stringent to hold the handle of the cup with a towel. It may be why we wash a third time (instead of twice) i.e., before bread. It may also be why (just speculating) we are told to dip our hand in the mikvah water before holding a kli to toivel.

But a woman (and possibly also a man) can/always does immerse with wet hair. Why?

(I know she toivels more than once, so presumably one of the tevilot is kosher. But it seems she makes a bracha before even the first? Wouldn't that be a  hefsek if the first dip is not a mitzvah immresion? Wouldn't it be ideal for her to dry her hair first [or else make the bracha after immersing]? Does anyone insist on this? )

Comment: water that comes in contact with a mikvah becomes part of the mikvah. by hand-washing it does not come into contact with a mikva. the wetting hand for kelim is the opposite: since it becomes part of the mikva there is no chatzisih via your hand if your hand is wet, as the water on your hand is touching the keli there.

Comment: for hand washing, the water that was on the hands before washing and cantransmit uncleanness to the water coming from the keli. In Mikveh, water are not unclean. note that in my explanation you don't see problem of chatsitsa.

Comment: @kouty Nevertheless washing with a reviis is enough to remove uncleanness coming from the keli or wet hands!

Comment: @Avrohom Yitschok the uncleanness comes from the hands. the hands are sheniot. The water drops on the hands can make the coming water unclean (old remembering, not verifyied now)

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76947/759

Comment: "I know she toivels more than once" Actually Rambam writes (Hilkhot Mikvaot 1:9) that multiple tevillot are inappropriate.

Comment: "But she makes a bracha before even the first?" Are you asking when one makes the berakha? Before the first [and only] tevilla according to most Rishonim. After the first [and only] tevilla according to a minority of Rishonim.

Comment: @mevaqesh A minor point, but are all rishonim really agreed on one tevila?

Comment: @SAH TTBOMK. I wouldn't be shocked if there were some mystically inclined Rishon who suggested multiples, but I am not aware of any. Consider asking about it separately if you are interested in the topic. Something like: "I am know that many people perform multiple tevillot. What is the reason and source for this?"

Comment: @mevaqesh Ahh maybe I will, bli neder. But now I'm curious. People today perform only one tevila? With keilim I believe it, but even for a woman? I had thought most everyone did [at least] 3? It seems there might be practical reasons, not only mystical to do more than one i.e. in case one turns out not to be kosher

Comment: @SAH That is certainly not the case. There is a popular (but dubious) practice of two tevillot that dates from the 16th century. I can only imagine that three is a mystical practice. I have not found 3 in a brief search of literature. I suspect it was only popularised relatively recently (in the last century or two at most). Arokh HaShulhan for example, in describing the custom only describes two; not three.

Answer (score -1):

Use a reviit on your hands and don't worry about wet hands or drops of water!

Mikveh is unrelated and has no issues like this, go in fully wet after your shower with no problems!

Comment: You need to give sources and explanations for your answers.